# Can I prevent OpenLayers from losing my WFS-T feature edits?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs-t

Using openlayers (2.12) and drawing some vector features against a WFS-T interface (offered by geoserver).

Problem is, when I draw some geometries and pan a little bit too much, openlayers sends "wfs:GetFeature" message to WFS-T interface, and while doing this it resets all features I have drawn so far.

You can try this even using the public openlayers examples: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

1. draw some features
2. pan / zoom around enough / too much before saving
3. the features you drew disappear

Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems there is no simple way to prevent this from happening. I ended up following advice on:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Can-I-prevent-OpenLayers-from-losing-my-WFS-T-feature-edits-td5042133.html

What I do is that I configure a larger than normal ratio for the layer:

```js
wfsLayerP = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "layername",
        {
            strategies : [ new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ratio: 100})],
```

This is feasible since my layer does not contain much data when editing it. Changing ratio from 2 -> 100 almost completely removes GetFeature requests while panning / zooming reasonable amounts and solves the problem.